# Rebuilding indexes does not change the fragmentation % for nonclustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

For starters, I am no DBA and I am working on rebuilding the indexes.

I made use of the amazing TSQL script from msdn to alter index based onthe fragmente percent returned by dm_db_index_physical_stats and if the fragment percent is more than 30 then do a REBUILD or do a REORGANISE.

What I found out was, in the first iteration, there were 87 records which needed defrag.I ran the script and all the 87 indexes (clustered & nonclustered) were rebuilt or reindexed. When I got the stats from dm_db_index_physical_stats , there were still 27 records which needed defrag and all of theses were NON CLUSTERED Indexes. All the Clustered indexes were fixed.

No matter how many times I run the script to defrag these records, I still have the same indexes to be defraged and most of them with the same fragmentation %. Nothing seems to change after this.

Note: I did not perform any inserts/ updates/ deletes to the tables during these iterations. Still the Rebuild/reorganise did not result in any change.

More information:  Using SQL 2008
Script as available in msdn  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx

Could you please explain why these 27 records of non clustered indexes are not being changed/ modified ?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Nod

Comment: Can you pelase provide the output with some statistics of one of the 27 as example?

Comment: I have pasted below one of the index results for 3 iterations.
the first iteration changed the fragmentation % a bit where as the 2nd and 3rd had no impact.

Index = [IX_BatchNumber]

Fragment % returned by dm_db_index_physical_stats 
Iteration 1 = 52.6315789473684
Iteration 2 = 41.1764705882353
Iteration 3 = 41.1764705882353 

There are other indteresting instances where in before the very first defrag the fragmentation % value was 30 and in the next to it jumped up to 40 and stays there forever.But this happened for only a couple of records. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

SQL Server will not rebuild indexes that are not large enough.  Have a look a the fragment_count (that's one of the fields in the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats view), it's probably quite low for those 27 indexes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a index that has over a million pages and is 31% fragmented.  Really would like an answer.

Comment: FYI see the answers on dba.stackexchange.com here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18372/why-index-rebuild-does-not-reduce-index-fragmentatation